# AWS Lambda denied accees to a API request, need alternative methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, permission-denied

I am trying to send a GET request to `https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?from=01-01-2023&series=%5B%22EQ%22%5D&symbol=PAYTM&to=24-01-2023`. It works fine if I run it locally, on VS Code's Thunder Client, Postman on web etc, i.e. the request is working fine. The code is also working perfectly. But when I construct a lambda function for it on AWS, it gives and error with Content-Type http/text whereas it should be giving gzip encoding. This is the error it is giving:

> You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity" on this server. Reference #18.9832d417.1675774874.1bc46bd8

**So basically the issue is that AWS Lambda is being denied access to the resources of the destination server. My question being, is there any alternative method on lambda to make this request work? Do I need to add some proxy? Do I need any workaround?**

This is the [Postman link](https://www.postman.com/augmatech/workspace/personal/collection/14878517-93b8cc8f-61c6-4f1f-9d37-f6424928adea?action=share&creator=14878517) if anyone wants to cross-check the req. First run [Initial cookie fetch](https://www.postman.com/augmatech/workspace/personal/request/14878517-13e00e62-e023-4f64-9b09-caa4223dfbca) and use the cookies in response for the next request: [Historical data](https://www.postman.com/augmatech/workspace/personal/request/14878517-97c5a5b9-15dd-4870-a549-e8bff807865b) which actually fetches the data from the intended server

I am posting the minimal code after cutting out the jargon (working perfectly fine), if anyone wants to try it on their own.

```golang
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type DailyDataType struct {
    ID                  string  `json:"_id"`
    Symbol              string  `json:"CH_SYMBOL"`
    Series              string  `json:"CH_SERIES"`
    MarkeyType          string  `json:"CH_MARKET_TYPE"`
    High                float32 `json:"CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE"`
    Low                 float32 `json:"CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE"`
    Open                float32 `json:"CH_OPENING_PRICE"`
    Close               float32 `json:"CH_CLOSING_PRICE"`
    LTP                 float32 `json:"CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE"`
    PrevClose           float32 `json:"CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE"`
    TotalTradedQuantity int32   `json:"CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY"`
    TotalTradedValue    float64 `json:"CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL"`
    High52W             float32 `json:"CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE"`
    Low52W              float32 `json:"CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE"`
    TotalTrades         int32   `json:"CH_TOTAL_TRADES"`
    ISIN                string  `json:"CH_ISIN"`
    ChTimestamp         string  `json:"CH_TIMESTAMP"`
    Timestamp           string  `json:"TIMESTAMP"`
    CreatedAt           string  `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt           string  `json:"updatedAt"`
    V                   int8    `json:"__v"`
    VWAP                float32 `json:"VWAP"`
    MTimestamp          string  `json:"mTIMESTAMP"`
}

type SecurityDataType struct {
    Meta interface{}     `json:"meta"`
    Data []DailyDataType `json:"data"`
}

var BaseURL string = "https://www.nseindia.com"

func ReqConfig() *http.Request {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", BaseURL, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "*/*")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.Add("Host", "www.nseindia.com")
    req.Header.Add("Referer", "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity")
    req.Header.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    req.Header.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "empty")
    req.Header.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "cors")
    req.Header.Add("pragma", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin")
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36")

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    for _, cookie := range res.Cookies() {
        req.AddCookie(cookie)
    }

    cookies := req.Cookies()
    for i := 0; i < len(cookies); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(cookies); j++ {
            if cookies[i].Name == cookies[j].Name {
                cookies = append(cookies[:j], cookies[j+1:]...)
                j--
            }
        }
    }
    req.Header.Del("Cookie")
    for _, cookie := range cookies {
        req.AddCookie(cookie)
    }

    return req
}

func FetchHistoricalData(symbol string, from string, to string, series string) (SecurityDataType, error) {
    req := ReqConfig()

    query := req.URL.Query()
    query.Add("symbol", symbol)
    query.Add("from", from)
    query.Add("to", to)
    query.Add("series", "[\""+series+"\"]")
    req.URL.RawQuery = query.Encode()
    req.URL.Path = "/api/historical/cm/equity"

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 40 * time.Second}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    var securityData SecurityDataType
    if err != nil {
        return securityData, err
    }

    switch res.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") {
    case "gzip":
        var gzipReader io.ReadCloser
        gzipReader, _ = gzip.NewReader(res.Body)
        err = json.NewDecoder(gzipReader).Decode(&securityData)
        defer gzipReader.Close()
    case "application/json":
        var results map[string]interface{}
        err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&results)
    default:
        bodyBytes, _ := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
        bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
        return securityData, errors.New(bodyString)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return securityData, err
    }

    return securityData, err
}

func HandleRequest() {
    dateToday := time.Now()
    dateYesterday := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1)
    data, err := FetchHistoricalData("JSL", dateYesterday.Format("02-01-2006"), dateToday.Format("02-01-2006"), "EQ")
}
func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
    // HandleRequest()
}
```

Comment: It looks like they are blocking access from anything in the AWS network.  A proxy *may* help but it may be blocked too.  There isn't much you can do about it as they control the data and access.  Another option is to rent a small server outside of the AWS network, have it grab the data and put it into, for example, a DynamoDB, and then use the Lambda to retrieve.  You have to decide if that is acceptable under the terms of use of the site.

Comment: Are there any decent chaces of it working if I switch to other cloud providers, or maybe use EC2 instead of lambda?

Comment: I would expect an EC2 and other cloud providers to have the same problem but it's impossible for me to say for sure.  Maybe a smaller hosting provider but, again, a guess.